# Changing the grouping of an user defined infix operator

Tags: operators, custom-notation

How can I change the default grouping on an operator without a built-in meaning?

I've created my own infix operator by defining `LeftArrow`.

```
SetAttributes[LeftArrow, {NumericFunction, OneIdentity}]
ex1_ ← ex2_ := ex1 /. Rule[ex2[[1]], ex2[[2]]]
```

*(I'm using the `Esc<-Esc` form of `LeftArrow` in the second line)*

When I use it, I need to string together applications like so:

```
eqIld2 = (((((((eqIld ← eqVrx) ← eqVct) ← eqIcr) ← eqVct) ← eqIcl) ← eqVtx) ← eqIin)
```

I'd like to be able to avoid all the parentheses, and to get the same result for the same input with the parentheses removed.

I don't see the default grouping for `LeftArrow` documented anywhere.  I've tried playing with various Attributes, but I can't find one that does what I want.  It looks like there's an `InfixNotation` that accepts options, but they aren't documented.

What's the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edit

As it was correctly noted the `Notation` package is not necessary here and the key point is recursive definition which builds the desired ordering:

```
LeftArrow[x_,y_,z__] := LeftArrow[LeftArrow[x,y],z] ;
```

Notice that the `z__` argument is followed by a double underscore, which allows the pattern to match an arbitrary number of arguments.

### Original answer

Perhaps Notation package might help:

```
<< Notation` ;
f[x_,y_,z__] := f[f[x,y],z] ;
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"x_", " ", "\[LeftArrow]", " ", "y_", " "}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{" ", RowBox[{"f", "[", RowBox[{"x_", ",", "y_"}], "]"}]}]]] ;
```

then try:

```
a \[LeftArrow] b
a \[LeftArrow] b \[LeftArrow] c
a \[LeftArrow] b \[LeftArrow] c \[LeftArrow] d
a \[LeftArrow] b \[LeftArrow] c \[LeftArrow] d \[LeftArrow] e
```

Comment: Thanks!  Turns out the Notation package isn't necessary.  If I just add `LeftArrow[ex1_, ex2_, ex3__] := LeftArrow[LeftArrow[ex1, ex2], ex3]`, it seems to do the trick.  I'm new to Mathematica, and the recursive definition wasn't intuitive, but it's good to know that the more specific match is identified and made first.  I think if you remove the reference to Notation, and add text to emphasize the double underscore on the `z__` arg (which I overlooked for a while), then this is the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You are right, `Notation` package is not needed here. I used it just because I had a similar problem and just copied my example with minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind mucking with the internal file `UnicodeCharacters.tr` (make a copy first!) you can change the line:

```
0x2190  ←   ($<-$ $&LeftArrow;$ $\leftarrow$ $\gets$)   Infix   380 None    5   5
```

to:

```
0x2190  ←   ($<-$ $&LeftArrow;$ $\leftarrow$ $\gets$)   Infix   380 Left    5   5
```

and then close and relaunch Mathematica so that the changes take affect. Afterwards I get:

```
a ← b ← c //FullForm
```

> LeftArrow[LeftArrow[a,b],c]